# Is there a variant of APCs that interrupts the target thread without waiting for an alertable wait?

Tags: winapi, signals, apc, interrupt

Is there a variant of APCs, or some other technique in NT-based Windows OSes, that will force a specific thread to call a specific user function immediately (or, at least, interrupting user code), without waiting for the thread to enter an alertable wait?

I realize this can lead to all kinds of concurrency issues. The main goal I'd like to use it for is forcing a processor level memory barrier from another thread (and waiting for completion) - other methods to achieve this would be helpful, but I'm still curious if this is possible at all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it, but it is not pretty.  Since the thread is not expecting this, you will be very limited in what you can call.  For example, you will not be able to call anything that uses any synchronization API.

If you still want to do it - `SuspendThread`,  `GetThreadContext`, `SetThreadContext`, and `ResumeThread` will allow you to simulate a function call.  You will have to preserve all registers, including the flags.

Obviously, this require platform-specific code.  Also note that some user-mode code touches locations that are above the stack pointer so you may want to add some margin to the pushed return address.

Comment: An interesting approach, if a bit frightening. Is it safe to call `ReleaseSemaphore` from such a context? I need to be able to communicate to the triggering thread that I'm done. Ideally I'd like to have the kernel handle everything in a single call though - Suspend->Resume could require two or more IPIs...

Comment: Yes, you can call ReleaseSemaphore from this context since this translates almost directly to a syscall.  I can think of better ways to implement RCU.  For example with a per-thread data structure (`TlsGetVAlue`).

Answer (score 1):

No, because that in general violates assumptions held by the other thread. The other thread must assume it can be interrupted by the kernel, yes, but not user-mode code changing the process working set.

Comment: I understand this can be dangerous in general. I would like to use this to implement Userspace RCU; certain RCU protocols require a way to trigger a processor memory barrier in other threads. Since literally all the interrupting function will be doing is invoking a memory barrier primitive, then bumping a semaphore to acknowledge, I don't expect state corruption to be an issue.